# CASE expression for Overlapping Data

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

Need to produce Custom Column based on year column

```
year <= '2017' THEN 'Old Cars'
year BETWEEN '2018' AND '2023' THEN 'New Cars'
year = '2023' THEN 'Current Year Cars'
```

Note: There is overlapping of year 2023 in New Cars and Future Cars.

Expected Result:

```
2015 - Old Cars
2016 - Old Cars
2017 - Old Cars

2018 - New Cars
2019 - New Cars
2020 - New Cars
2021 - New Cars
2022 - New Cars
2023 - New Cars

2023 - Current Year Cars
```

Comment: It's unclear to me what your problem is. But you should check for `= 2023`  before checking the BETWEEN condition.

Comment: Would you be better to do a count, and then have a separate column in your result set for each category?  That way, you'd be able to check for 2023 in both new cars and current cars.  

__*COUNT(CASE WHEN year BETWEEN '2018' AND '2023' THEN 1 END) AS NewCars,
COUNT(CASE WHEN year = '2023' THEN 1 END) AS CurrentYearCars*__

Comment: Can you share the definition of your table and some data